# update all entries inside a SQL column with @PostPersit in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

I'm trying to update automaticly all entries of a new sql column with the @PostPersist anotation.

the model :

```
int id;
String firstName;
String SecondName;
String Maths;

@AutoWired
ModelService modelService;

@PostPersist
public void setMathsWithPostPersist(){
        if(Maths == null) {
            Maths = modelService.calculate(id);
        }
    }
```

Then, here's the service:

```
public int calculateById(int id){
        Model model = modelRepository.getById(id);
        int number = calculateNumber(model);
        model.setMaths(number);
        modelRepository.save(organisme);
        return number;
    }
```

I don't know if it's due to the fact that I'm using an autowired in the model class, that's my first use of @PostPersist.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@PostPersist` listener is only invoked when "persisting" an entity, but what you are doing here is an update of an existing entity, so you would have to use `@PostUpdate` instead.